# How to verify if value already added to the list and if so, then update the value?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use 3 lists to store field name, its value and score. If field name is already added to according list, then I just need to update other 2 lists. If it is not there, then I need to add it. I do the following:

```
user = User.get_by_key_name(user_key_name)
if user:
    field_names = user.field_names
    field_values = user.field_values
    field_scores = user.field_scores
    if field_name in user.field_names:
        # field_names[field_index] = field_name
        field_index = user.field_names.index(field_name)
        field_values[field_index] = field_value
        field_scores[field_index] = field_score
    else:
        field_names.append(field_name)
        field_values.append(field_value)
        field_scores.append(field_score)
    user.field_names = field_names
    user.field_values = field_values 
    user.field_scores = field_scores
    user.put()
```

Is it correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

```
user = User.get_by_key_name(user_key_name)
if user:
```

Python convention is to use `user is None` when checking against `None`

```
    field_names = user.field_names
    field_values = user.field_values
    field_scores = user.field_scores
```

Why copy these references? It doesn't help you much.

```
    if field_name in user.field_names:
        # field_names[field_index] = field_name
        field_index = user.field_names.index(field_name)
```

Use index to check if field_name is present. That way it doesn't have to search through the lists twice.

```
        field_values[field_index] = field_value
        field_scores[field_index] = field_score
```

If possible, avoid maintaing parrallel lists. In this case, it looks like maybe you should have a dictionary of strings to tuples.

```
    else:
        field_names.append(field_name)
        field_values.append(field_value)
        field_scores.append(field_score)
    user.field_names = field_names
    user.field_values = field_values 
    user.field_scores = field_scores
```

Unless user does something odd, this has no effect. Assignment doesn't copy in python, it just copies the references.

```
    user.put()
```

Comment: I wanted to mention that in tags, but there is no GAE tag. So, this code is used with GAE.

If I use `field_index` to identify if value is there and it is not, then I get `ValueError`.

Not sure how to save tuples in GAE datastore - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442860/how-to-properly-save-data-in-gae-datastore/9447170#9447170

Comment: @LA_, you should catch the ValueError and handle it. I don't know GAE, and you may not able to store tuples.